# Failed to install custom lib deployed on Sonatype Nexus Pypi repository

Tags: python, python-3.x, pip, nexus, pypi

- pip:    18.0
- python: 3.6
- Nexus:  3.13

We have a corporate Nexus installed for hosting internal libraries, and a hosted pypi repository has been created.

I was able to deploy a wheel file following [this instruction](https://packaging.python.org/tutorials/packaging-projects/), but failed to install it locally.

Command to install:

`python -m pip install --index-url https://xxxx/xxx-pypi/ 'customlib==0.0.1' -v`

Error received:

> Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement customlib==0.0.1 (from versions: )
>   No matching distribution found for customlib==0.0.1

**Please advise on this issue. Thanks in advance!**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your index URL isn't correct, see here for how to configure pip to work with Nexus Repo 3:

https://help.sonatype.com/display/NXRM3/PyPI+Repositories#PyPIRepositories-ConfiguringPyPIClientTools